# Exporting training samples object statistics in eCognition

Tags: export, ecognition

I have training samples collected for my four sites. I need to run CART for feature selection off eCognition. The only way I know is to recollect samples using manual classification which is not desired. Is there any way which I can directly convert samples to object statistics with classes and features? or at least convert samples to classification as it is easier to export from classification to object statistics. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Export>Export_Results>Export_Type select "statistics", you should have Edited and Applied NN standards;

I personally would use grass gis's i.segment + r.to.vect + v.rast.stats